# How should I recover service of Apache IoTDB when reporting "Fetch Schema failed" error after restarting?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

After Apache IoTDB's service is restarted, an error will be reported both in inserting data and querying data. The error message is: "java. lang.RuntimeExpception: Fetch Schema failed." Now I use IoTDB Version 1.0.0, wonder how to deal with this error?